# NextGen - Display Image Count Per Gallery

Tags: gallery

I am using the NextGen gallery WordPress plugin for a site. In my gallery.php template I want to retrieve the number of images for each gallery displayed in the loop. I cannot figure out a way to get the data and print it under the thumbnail of each gallery that's called in gallery.php

Here is where I want to insert the gallery image count and print it:

```
<?php 
global $wpdb; 
$images = intval( $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->nggpictures") ); ?> 
<a rel="prettyPhoto" href="<?php echo $image->imageURL ?>" <?php $image->thumbcode ?>>
    <span>view</span>
</a>
<?php echo $images; ?> pictures
```

Comment: I remember using [custom templates](http://www.nextgen-gallery.com/nextgen-gallery-templates/) for NextGen, can you not just [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) the images in the array?

Comment: Hello Christian,
Yes, I am using a custom template for the gallery. I just can't get each gallery displayed with the code above to display it for each array. Advice?

Comment: Do you want a single page with a link to each gallery? If so I would suggest using the [Album](http://www.nextgen-gallery.com/albums/) feature, as I think that's exactly what you want.

Comment: Yeah, I like the album feature and how it counts the number of galleries. I just need that sort of function for images per gallery. So it would print the number of images in a gallery.

Comment: If you are outputting a gallery then there is a global called `$images` just use `echo count( $images )`. However if you are listing all galleries without being in an albumn and want to show the number of images I will have to do some more digging.

Comment: Hello Christian, yes this is what I want and it's driving me nuts!

Comment: Hi Ian, if you review my comment, please tell me which path you need to take as they are different.

Comment: Hello Christian, sorry for the confusion. I need to list all of the galleries and show the number of images within each gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your above code, you were just missing the WHERE clause. Hopefully that should work.

```
<?php 
global $wpdb; 
$images = intval( $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->nggpictures WHERE galleryid = {$gallery->ID}") ); ?> 
<a rel="prettyPhoto" href="<?php echo $image->imageURL ?>" <?php $image->thumbcode ?>>
    <span>view</span>
</a>
<?php echo $images; ?> pictures
```

It's not the best way to implement it, but if it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $postid !='' ) {
    $set = ci_featgal_get_attachments();
    $i = 0;
    while ( $set->have_posts() ) : $set->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'loop' ); 
        $i++;
    endwhile; 
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
    ?><h6 style="font-size:10px;color:#c9b07d;"><?php echo $i ." PHOTOS";?></h6><?php
}
```

Comment: Please file an [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/203164/edit) and explain why this would work.