# How can i count the images that are atacht to NextGEN Gallery

Tags: plugin-nextgen-gallery, advanced-custom-fields

How can i count images form NextGen Gallery, the NextGen Gallery is insite a custom field.

Custom field for NextGen Gallery is  " poze "

I search for it, i found this

[NextGen - Display Image Count Per Gallery](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73192/nextgen-display-image-count-per-gallery)

```
<?php 
global $wpdb; 
$images = intval( $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->nggpictures WHERE galleryid = {$gallery->ID}") ); ?> 
<?php echo $images; ?>
```

This code it display me the 0 count of pictures...

Mode 2 wath i try

```
  <?php 
        global $wpdb; 
        $images = intval( $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->nggpictures") ); ?> 
        <?php echo $images; ?>
```

This code it display me the all pictures of galery's...

Mode 3 wath i try

```
<?php $related_posts = get_field('poze');$count = 0;if( !empty($related_posts) ){$count = count( $related_posts ); }echo $count; ?>
```

This code is retriving me the number of galerry's

How can i retrive the number pof pictures atached to that gallery...
Ex: 12 pictures

How can i add the custom field (poze - where ID is stored) ... anny solution woud be apreciate.

Comment: Did you try to run the query directly in PHPMyAdmin? I suppose `$gallery->ID` is correct, right?

Comment: hy bransofilo, 
i am not so good with php, i found that in search.. 

"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->nggpictures" it count me all the pictures from all the gallery's.

I want to integgrate somhow the Custom Field ... the custom field is the ID of the Gallery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you actually have something in the $gallery object (hint: confirm that by `print_r($gallery)` in your template), then your code should work. Perhaps step back and leave the database stuff to NextGEN, just count the image IDs:

```
global $nggdb;
$poze = get_field('poze');
if ($poze && count($poze)) {
    $galleryID = $poze[0]['ngg_id'];
    $imageIDs = $nggdb->get_ids_from_gallery($galleryID);
    $count = count($imageIDs);
}
```

Comment: Note i use custom field to add galley


Custom field : poze

I tried this :
`<?php 
global $wpdb; 
$gallery = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'poze', true); 
$images = intval( $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->nggpictures WHERE galleryid = {$gallery->ID}") ); ?> 
<?php echo ($images); ?>`

when i print_r it retrive me the code UP

it retrive me this ..  `0Array ( [0] => Array ( [ngg_id] => 14 [ngg_form] => gallery ) ) 1) `

when i use that code

Comment: What does `get_field('poze');` return in your code? Have you confirmed that it's a gallery ID?

Comment: `<?php echo get_field('poze'); ?> ` it retrive me the word Array

[IMG]http://i49.tinypic.com/2vjy3rp.jpg

Left - The custom Field, Right - Were I select the Galley( EX: Fire with Fire

Comment: Right, you need to get the gallery ID from within that array. `print_r(get_field('poze'));` to see what it has in it.

Comment: retrive me this `Array ( [0] => Array ( [ngg_id] => 24 [ngg_form] => gallery ) ) )`

24 is the id of gallery

Comment: @Batman: please see updated answer

Comment: doesent work, it retrive me nothing... http://i49.tinypic.com/21eztid.jpg

Comment: You need to echo the `$count` somewhere. That's up to you. Go try!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7250/discussion-between-batman-and-webaware)

Comment: i go to chat but you arent? im solo :D

Comment: verry god answers... verry good coder . Thanks Webaware